# Any way to prevent stupid Xcode updates to Storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoa

Xcode keep bothering me for years with updates like this one

```
+++ b/Project/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
@@ -890,8 +890,6 @@ some existing one.</string>
     <resources>
         <image name="TabBarButton" width="65" height="15"/>
         <image name="TabBarHome" width="25" height="25"/>
-        <image name="TabBarHome" width="25" height="25"/>
-        <image name="TabBarSettings" width="25" height="25"/>
         <image name="TabBarSettings" width="25" height="25"/>
         <image name="TrashCan" width="13" height="15"/>
     </resources>
```

You may think that I really have duplicated lines. Okay, but next time Xcode does this:

```
+++ b/Project/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
@@ -890,8 +890,6 @@ some existing one.</string>
     <resources>
         <image name="AddBrick" width="65" height="15"/>
         <image name="TabBarHome" width="25" height="25"/>
+        <image name="TabBarHome" width="25" height="25"/>
+        <image name="TabBarSettings" width="25" height="25"/>
         <image name="TabBarSettings" width="25" height="25"/>
         <image name="TrashCan" width="13" height="15"/>
     </resources>
```

Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: Didn't you add a new resource named `AddBrick`? What's the problem?

Comment: @Desdenova: That's not the issue. The plus signs indicate new lines, but those lines are duplicates as the TabBarHome and TabBarSettings resources are there twice now.

Comment: @Desdenova No, I didn't. Neither I even changed storyboard — Xcode does this "optimization" automatically on file open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "No". Storyboards are complicated documents containing serialized object graphs, along with those objects parentage, and the graphical diagram of the storyboard GUI. Xcode will make a lot of changes anytime you touch an object in the storyboard, or change the class definition of anything instantiated in the Storyboard. Just think of it as a black box.

Comment: I frequently saw this behavior described as an Xcode bug, how do you think?

Comment: If you think it's a bug, file a RADAR and attach examples like this and your storyboard file. Apple actively uses RADAR to determine what to prioritize.

Comment: Even though it's not a bug, but feature, it's still leads to problems when you use Git in a team. It creates a lot of totally unnecessary merge conflicts, which takes time to solve and can lead to actual bugs. So it's not really a RADAR issue, it just sucks!

Comment: RADARs _are_ used to track feature requests and improvements, so if it's something you really hate then you should file a RADAR. If they get enough, they're more likely to change it. Or, switch platforms - I jumped to Xamarin and Flutter, in part because of the terrible designer experience with Xcode.